# Can unprotected SSH be an issue if port 22 is open locally but not externally?

Tags: ssh

Let's say I'm running a webserver from home that has port 8080 exposed to the internet. I SSH into that server from another computer on my local network on port 22. If port 22 is not accessible externally, is there a danger to keeping the SSH connection unprotected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, frankly. If you get a compromise in your network, one of the first things a worm-type malware will do is scan the local network for SSH.

Alternatively, if your webserver is compromised and the nature of the vulnerability means that the attacker can get network access, they might try to connect to the ssh port from the web service and get higher privileges.

But then it all comes down to what you mean by "unprotected". While I might not go crazy with firewall rules (although I might lock down the webserver's ssh to just your normal computer that ssh'es to it, if that's possible), having a very strong password or key-based authentication is advised.